# Pentaho does not run and in console it gives the error of ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCDODING?

Tags: pentaho

When I run pentaho it loads some scripts and files but some of them fails with the error of:

```
ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCDODING
```

In console I see that `$` is undefined for jQuery.

[image]

I didn't change anything. Once I reran the pentaho and it worked, but it does not work at all.

Is there something I could do about it? What this mean? I searched for `CDF.js` file and I saw that the file is present.

Any help?

Comment: what is the problem?
your server not starting?
JS will not be the reason for server start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that `/var/` partition was full 100% and pentaho, nginx could not log at all. Nginx could cache results.

By freeing space the problem went away.